# Finding all paths using recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

I have a problem I am trying to do to practice, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to write a recursive algorithm for it. I have a file that is laid out like so:

```
4
(())
()((
(()(
))))
```

This problem is from USACO. http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=189

The problem statement is copy-pasted below:

> Although Bessie the cow finds every string of balanced parentheses to
>   be aesthetically pleasing, she particularly enjoys strings that she
>   calls "perfectly" balanced -- consisting of a string of ('s followed
>   by a string of )'s having the same length.  For example:
>
> (((())))
>
> While walking through the barn one day, Bessie discovers an N x N grid
>   of horseshoes on the ground, where each horseshoe is oriented so that
>   it looks like either ( or ).  Starting from the upper-left corner of
>   this grid, Bessie wants to walk around picking up horseshoes so that
>   the string she picks up is perfectly balanced.  **Please help her
>   compute the length of the longest perfectly-balanced string she can
>   obtain.**
>
> In each step, Bessie can move up, down, left, or right. She can only
>   move onto a grid location containing a horseshoe, and when she does
>   this, she picks up the horseshoe so that she can no longer move back
>   to the same location (since it now lacks a horseshoe).  She starts by
>   picking up the horseshoe in the upper-left corner of the grid.  Bessie
>   only picks up a series of horseshoes that forms a perfectly balanced
>   string, and she may therefore not be able to pick up all the
>   horseshoes in the grid.

I am having issues trying to figure out how I would create an algorithm that found the best possible path recursively. Can anyone point me in the right direction, or have any examples I could look at to get an idea? I've been searching but all examples I've found are from one point to another, and not finding all possible paths within a matrix/array.

```
package bessiehorseshoe;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BessieHorseShoe {

    int answer = 0;
    int matrixSize = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BessieHorseShoe goBessieGo = new BessieHorseShoe();
    }

    BessieHorseShoe() throws IOException {
        int rowFilled = 0;
        int currentColumn = 0;
        int character = 0;

        BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("hshoe.in"));
        String inputLine = inputFile.readLine();
        matrixSize = Character.digit(inputLine.charAt(0), 10);
        System.out.println(matrixSize);

        char[][] pMatrix = new char[matrixSize][matrixSize];

        while ((character = inputFile.read()) != -1) {
            char c = (char) character;
            if (c == '(' || c == ')') {
                pMatrix[rowFilled][currentColumn] = c;
                System.out.print(pMatrix[rowFilled][currentColumn]);
                rowFilled++;
                if (rowFilled == matrixSize) {
                    currentColumn++;
                    rowFilled = 0;
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
        matchHorseShoes(pMatrix);
    }

    public int matchHorseShoes(char[][] pMatrix) {
        if (pMatrix[0][0] == ')') {
            System.out.println("Pattern starts with ')'. No possible path!");
            return 0;
        }
        System.out.println("Works");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following algorithm will solve your problem. You can also use memoization to speed up the running time.
The idea is simple:

- while opening parentheses increment the count of opened parentheses;
- if you star closing, you must continue to close and increment the closed parentheses;
- if you are closing and the number of closed parentheses are greater or equal to the number of opened parentheses, stop and return this value.

All the rest of the code is syntactic sugar. (From the returned list of items visited is trivial obtail the output you desire).

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class USACO {

static class Path {

    public List<String> items;
    public int value;

    public Path() {
        this.items = new LinkedList<String>();
        this.value = 0;
    }

}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final int n = 5;
    final String[][] input = new String[n][n];
    // Create a random input of size n
    for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
            input[y][x] = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "(" : ")";
            System.out.print(input[y][x] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    final Path bestPath = longestPath(n, input, 0, 0, 0, 0, input[0][0] == "(");
    System.out.println("Max:" + bestPath.value + "\n" + bestPath.items);
}

public static Path longestPath(final int n, final String[][] input, final int x, final int y, int numberOpened, int numberClosed,
        final boolean wasOpening) {
    if (input == null) {
        return new Path();
    } else if (!wasOpening && (numberClosed >= numberOpened)) { // Reached a solution
        final Path path = new Path();
        path.value = numberOpened;
        path.items.add("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
        return path;
    } else if ((x < 0) || (y < 0) || (x >= n) || (y >= n)) { // Out of bound
        return new Path();
    } else if (input[y][x] == "") { // Already visited this item
        return new Path();
    } else {
        final String parenthese = input[y][x];
        // Increment the number of consecutive opened or closed visited
        if (parenthese.equals("(")) {
            numberOpened++;
        } else {
            numberClosed++;
        }
        input[y][x] = ""; // Mark as visited
        Path bestPath = new Path();
        bestPath.value = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        // Explore the other items
        for (int dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++) {
            for (int dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++) {
                if (((dy == 0) || (dx == 0)) && (dy != dx)) { // go only up, down, left, right
                    final boolean opening = (parenthese == "(");
                    if (wasOpening || !opening) {
                        // Find the longest among all the near items
                        final Path possiblePath = longestPath(n, input, x + dx, y + dy, numberOpened, numberClosed, opening);
                        if (possiblePath.value > bestPath.value) {
                            bestPath = possiblePath;
                            bestPath.items.add("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        input[y][x] = parenthese; // mark as not visited
        return bestPath;
    }
}
```

}